# How to maintain state to highlighting selected node of a JQuery Treeview after Post Back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I have HTML code like this within sample.html file:

```
<ul id='topics' class='filetree'>
<li><span class='folder'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=#'>Topics</a></span>
<ul>
<li><span class='folder'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1'>Topic 1</a></span>
<ul>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.1'>Topic 1.1</a></span></li>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.2'>Topic 1.2</a></span></li>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.3'>Topic 1.3</a></span></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Using **JQuery.load** I load html file in order to generate Treeview

```
<div id="LtrLeftContent">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $('#LtrLeftContent').load('sample.html', function () {  
    $("#topics").treeview();  
    $("li span").click(function () {  
    alert($(this).text());    // Get the current node text
    });  
});                 
  </script>  
</div>
```

## Now the problem described bellow

After click on any node just as bellow node

```
<li><span class='folder'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1'>Topic 1</a></span></li>
```

post back occur & tree view unable to maintain the state of selected node.

I try bellow code but no success

**Process 1:**

```
$("li span").bind('click', function() {
  //clear all clicked items if any
  $('.selected').removeClass('select');
  //set this clicked
  $(this).addClass('select');
});
```

**Process 2: **

```
$("li span").click(function() {
  //clear all clicked items if any
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  //set this clicked
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**Question 1:** How to maintain the state of selected node after post back. For highlighted that particular node.

What is the uses of

```
persist: "cookie",
cookieId: "navigationtree"
```

Why It is unable to maintain the state ?

**Problem Solved**

```
$("#topics").treeview({
    persist: "location"
});
```

Very useful link with elaborate description

**Url :** [jQuery TreeView v1.4 doc](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm)

**Note:**  But don't know why using bellow code it is not working properly

```
persist: "cookie",
cookieId: "navigationtree"
```

Answer (score 1):

After a postback, everything is gone.  You need to store the ID of the selected node in a cookie.

However, your nodes don't have ID's, so you could store the text or the href in a cookie and then when the page loads, look for the cookie, if found, use jQuery to find the node and select it.